# Driving a mos with a dac

Tags: dac, nmos

I'm building a programmable current load.
The big picture is : A microcontroler (stm32f303) drives (through its dac) some n-mos 
(tested with PSMN034 and IRL2203) that drawn current. The microcontroler
also measure current and adjust the gate voltage until the current reach the target.

My problem is I have some strange behaviour while controling the mos' gate with
the DAC.

**For this test, I only output a fix value on the DAC**. With nothing connected to DAC, the output is stable. When connecting the gate to the DAC, I measure voltage oscillations on the DAC output. I supposed that the DAC was not able to 
provide enough  current, so I added a AOP but the result is the same.
With a fix DAC output, the oscillations' frequency is slowing down while the current is raising. The speed is "exponential". Current is growing from 20mA up to 1A, when I stop the experience.

I expected everything to be stable : DAC voltage and current drawn in mos.

Do you know what it can be ?

Thanks.

Here's a schematic:

Power is connected to a +8V power supply. The microcontoller is powered by a 3v regulator connected to my computer's usb port. AOP is powered by USB.
[image]

Here's a screenshot of the measures. The top curve is the DAC output. The bottom curve is the output of the AOP (tied to mos' gate).

[image]

and a video to see the frequency changing:
[Video](https://youtu.be/Z0pf8V3Ej9w)

Comment: What is "Power" connected to? And where do those connections either side of R35 go?

Comment: Perhaps using a current mirror is a more viable solution.

Comment: @Finbarrr : Power is connected to +8V, microcontroller is powered by the usb cable (it's a nucleo eval board). Ground of the two power supplies are connected together Connections from R35 are going to an amplifier used for future current measurement.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: I don't know this design. I will ask google. Thanks.

Comment: @Finbarr: More exactly the microcontroller is powered through a 3.3v regulator connected to USB. AOP is powered by USB.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the voltage on "Power", but the real problem you're going to have is that the design is flawed from the start. Relying on an ADC, software and DAC to provide a feedback loop is asking for instability as it's simply nowhere near fast enough.

Comment: Hum... You're right, the 8v (from HMP4030 power supply) is very noisy. I'm not planning to build an accurate current load. Before working on this, I was using a simple mos driven by potentiometer and the result was enough fine. For this design I replaced the potentiometer with a DAC. Both provide a voltage on mos' gate. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this behaviour out comes when a AOP drives a capacitive input like a mos' gate.
Added some filter and no more oscillation.

BTW, I found dozens of project like this on the net and obviously, like Finbarr says, using adc/dac to drive the system definitely not the best way.
A much better way (and an interesting way to learn AOP) is to let the AOP drive the mos with a loop back coming from low side current measurement. See here:
[enter link description here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Programmable-Constant-Current-Power-Resist/)